# phpseclib producing strange output

Tags: php, phpseclib

I have code which generates a text file on my server.  I then need this file uploaded to another server using sftp.  To start things off, I do

```
if(performLdapOperations()) {
    sleep(10);
    performFtpOperation();
}
```

performLdapOperations produces the text file and places it on my server, performFtpOperation takes this text file and uploads to another server.  This is my function

```
function performFtpOperation() {

    global $config;

    $local_directory = getcwd() .'/outputs/';
    $remote_directory = '/home/newfolder/';

    $sftp = new SFTP($config::FTP_SERVER, 22, 10);

    if (!$sftp->login($config::FTP_USER, $config::FTP_PASSWORD)) {
        exit('Login Failed');
    }

    $files_to_upload = array();

    /* Open the local directory form where you want to upload the files */
    if ($handle = opendir($local_directory))
    {
        /* This is the correct way to loop over the directory. */
        while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
        {
            if ($file != "." && $file != "..")
            {
                $files_to_upload[] = $file;
            }
        }

        closedir($handle);
    }

    if(!empty($files_to_upload))
    {
        /* Now upload all the files to the remote server */
        foreach($files_to_upload as $file)
        {
            $success = $sftp->put($remote_directory . $file,
                $local_directory . $file,
                NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
        }
    }
}
```

So the text file that is produces is in my outputs folder.  I then want to take this file and upload to a new server to the location /home/newfolder/

Everything seems to work, and the file seems to get uploaded to the new server.  However, when I open the file that has been uploaded, all it contains is the path of where the file is, nothing else.  The file on my server which is in the outputs folder contains everything, for some reason something is going wrong when sending it over sftp?

Is there anything in my code that may be causing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're using the 2.0 version of phpseclib, which is namespaced. If that's the case then the problem is with this line:

```
$success = $sftp->put($remote_directory . $file,
    $local_directory . $file,
    NET_SFTP_LOCAL_FILE);
```

Try this:

```
$success = $sftp->put($remote_directory . $file,
    $local_directory . $file,
    SFTP::SOURCE_LOCAL_FILE);
```